# BulkInsertOrUpdate Entity Framework Core with EFCore.BulkExtensions

Tags: entity-framework-core

The `BulkInsertOrUpdate` method throws an exception

> null value in column "id" of relation "table" violates not-null constraint

I am using **EFCore.BulkExtensions** for bulk operation.

This is what I have - model class:

```
public partial class NordocKind
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

`OnModelCreating` config:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<NordocKind>(entity =>
  {
      entity.HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName("nordoc_kinds_pkey");
      entity.ToTable("table", tb => tb);

      entity.Property(e => e.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedNever()
            .HasColumnName("id");
     
      entity.Property(e => e.Name)
            .HasMaxLength(500)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("''::bpchar")
            .HasColumnName("name");
});
```

Code:

```
using  var context = CreateContext();

NordocKind n = new NordocKind() { Id = 0, Name = "sss" };

context.BulkInsertOrUpdate(new List<NordocKind>() { n });
```

If I use `BulkInsert` or `context.Add(n); context.SaveChanges();`, it works fine, but `BulkInsertOrUpdate` throws an exeption.

I don't know why it is trying to set `id=null` if I have defined `ValueGeneratedNever()` for this property.

Is there a way to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: There's no such method in EF Core. There's no such thing as Bulk Update either. It seems you're using a third-party library with a name intentionally chosen to trick people into thinking it's part of EF Core. It's not

Comment: From which library `BulkInsertOrUpdate` method? Which DBMS you are using?

Comment: What that library does has nothing to do with EF in the first place. It does what all ETL jobs and scripts do - it inserts the data into a staging table (or worse, a temporary table or table variable) and then updates the target table first by doing an `UPDATE Target ... FROM Source INNER JOIN Target on Source.ID=Target.ID` and then inserts new rows with `INSERT ... FROM Source LEFT JOIN Target ... Where Target.ID is NULL`. Table variables and temporary tables are *both* stored in tempdb, an already busy database

Comment: `If i use BulkInsert or context.Add(n); context.SaveChanges();` those methods have nothing in common, in fact the second snippet is a red flag. That `BulkInsert` writes directly to the database, permanently. A DbContext on the other hand is a Unit-of-Work. SaveChanges persists *all* pending changes, in a batch, using an internal transaction. `DbContext.Add` doesn't add anything, it starts tracking an unrelated object for changes. The initial state will be `Added`. If you used `Update` then EF would determine the state based on the object's ID value, tracking it as `Modified` if it had a key

Comment: I am using EFCore.BulkExtensions.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, postgre sql

Comment: Hi, just to isolate the problem, did you try with `NordocKind n = new NordocKind() { Id = 1, Name = "sss" };` ? I mean, `0` is the default value for `long` and, maybe, the library 'thinks' that should save a null.

Comment: @daniherrera,I looked at the source code and saw that the library “thinks” that if id==0, then the DBMS should deal with “id” and does not add “id” to the query. Instead of insert (id, name), just insert (name). That's why I was getting this error. I had to separate such requests into an additional request.

Comment: Nice, post your own answer to help other devs ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the source code and saw that the library “thinks” that if id==0, then the DBMS should deal with “id” and does not add “id” to the query. Instead of insert (id, name), just insert (name). That's why I was getting this error. I had to separate such requests into an additional request